# ggplot2 grid_arrange_shared_legend change number of columns

Tags: r, pdf, plot, ggplot2

I am using `grid_arrange_shared_legend`, which I found [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Share-a-legend-between-two-ggplot2-graphs) to generate a grid of plots. I slightly modified `grid_arrange_shared_legend` to fit my needs:

```
grid_arrange_shared_legend <- function(plots) {
  g <- ggplotGrob(plots[[1]] + theme(legend.position="bottom"))$grobs
  legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]
  lheight <- sum(legend$height)
  grid.arrange(
    do.call(arrangeGrob, lapply(plots, function(x)
      x + theme(legend.position="none"))),
    legend,
    ncol = 1,
    heights = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lheight, lheight))
}
```

I call this function like that

```
pdf("plots.pdf",width=12.21/2.54, height=20.92/2.54)
grid_arrange_shared_legend(plotList) #ncol=length(ns), main = "Main title")
dev.off()
```

This generates a pdf file with 4 columns of plots (see [pdf1](http://www.docdroid.net/LTU3fOc/plots.pdf.html)). However, I need 3 columns instead. I tried achieving this by replacing `ncol=1` with `ncol=3` in `grid_arrange_shared_legend`. This results in all the plots being in the left column and the middle and right column being empty (see [pdf2](http://docdro.id/BFugdqa)).

**How can I achieve a 3 column plot?**

Comment: [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: That `ncol=1` is to put the plots and legend in one column. To arrange the plots themselves you need to pass a `ncol` argument to the `arrangeGrob.`.. so change that part to `do.call(arrangeGrob,   c(lapply(plots, function(x)    x + theme(legend.position="none")), ncol=3))`

Answer (score 1):

Changing `grid_arrange_shared_legend` to

```
grid_arrange_shared_legend <- function(plots) {
  g <- ggplotGrob(plots[[1]] + theme(legend.position="bottom"))$grobs
  legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]
  lheight <- sum(legend$height)
  grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(grobs=lapply(plots, function(x)
      x + theme(legend.position="none")),ncol = 3),
    legend,
    ncol = 1,
    heights = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lheight, lheight))
}
```

solved the issue. user20650 provided this solution in his comment.